# Realm Typecast issue Swift

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have to declare realm string property for to save the value get from API, but the issue is, I don't know which type of data will come from the server.
Sometimes I am getting String value and sometime Int.
Now how I will save data to the realm.

```
 class Fields: Object {
       @objc dynamic var default_value: String? = nil
    }
```

API Response

```
{
  access = 1;
  default_value = " ";
},
{
  access = 1;
  default_value = 20;
}
```

Comment: add sample api result

Comment: @a.masri please check update

Answer (score 0):

This is the safest (where `stringOrInt` is the value you're receiving from the API):

`fieldsObject.default_value = stringOrInt as? String`

But you can also use **string interpolation** and inject the value directly into a string literal:

`fieldsObject.default_value = "\(stringOrInt)"`

Comment: This is for showing value, But my question is how to save on realm DB

Comment: The title of your question is `Realm Typecast issue Swift`, not `How do I save data to Realm`.

Comment: Check my Description

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution

1- Relam object class

```
class Fields: Object {
    @objc dynamic private var default_value: String? = nil

    @objc var defaultValue: Any?{
        didSet{
            self.default_value = "\(defaultValue!)"
        }
    }
    open override class func ignoredProperties()->[String] {

        return ["defaultValue"]
    }
}
```

1- Test add object in you'r DB

```
 let obj = Fields()
        obj.defaultValue = "ahmad"

        let obj2 = Fields()
        obj2.defaultValue = 1

        let realm = try! Realm()
        try! realm.write {

            realm.add([obj,obj2])
        }
```

3- Result

[image]

Comment: I got this error ,Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Invalid value '26' of type '__NSCFNumber' for 'string?' property 'Fields.default_value'.'

Comment: You must migration you're database or try uninstall app and reinstall

Comment: I reinstall the app

Comment: I have this type of json Objects, {
  access = 1;
  default_value = " ";
},
{
  access = 1;
  default_value = 20;
}

Comment: And I save data directly Like....
 static func SaveTaskData(data : NSArray) {
        let realm = try! Realm()
        try! realm.write {
            for i in 0 ..< data.count {
                realm.create(SaveTaskDatabase.self, value: data[i] , update: true)
            }
        }
    }

Comment: @InderpalSingh this line `realm.create(Fields.self, value: item, update: false)` not working with  `settar ` value , Please make sure parse json object to  `Fields ` 

please check this how to parse json to objects  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/decodable